# Selecting unique records from database

Tags: sql

Running this query,

```
select * from table;
```

Returns the following

```
|branch | number |
-------------------
|  1    |  123   |
|  1    |  001   |
|  2    |  123   |
|  3    |  123   |
|  4    |  123   |
|  1    |  123   |
|  1    |  789   |
|  2    |  123   |
|  3    |  123   |
|  4    |  009   |
```

I want to find values that are unique to ONLY branch 1

```
|  1    |  001   |
|  1    |  789   |
```

Can this be done without the data being stored in separate tables? I've tried a few "select distinct" queries & don't seem to get the results I'm expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess what I'm trying to say is that I want to find all numbers that are unique to ONLY branch 1. If they are found in any other branch, I don't want to see them.

I guess this is what you want.

```
SELECT distinct number
FROM MyTable
WHERE branch=1 and number not in 
( SELECT distinct number
FROM MyTable
WHERE branch != 1 )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT branch, number
FROM table
WHERE branch = 1
GROUP BY branch, number
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need any aggregates, you can use `distinct` instead of `group by`:

```
select  distinct branch
,       number
from    YourTable
where   branch = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. Running that query will return "number" column values that may be found in other branches.  I guess what I'm trying to say is that I want to find all numbers that are unique to ONLY branch 1. If they are found in any other branch, I don't want to see them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT branch, number
FROM table
GROUP BY branch, number
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06bd8/2) for you to have a look at

If you want to limit it to only branch 1, then just add a where clause.

```
SELECT branch, number
FROM table
WHERE branch = 1
GROUP BY branch, number
```

Answer (score 0):

To select all values that are unique in column `number` and have a `branch` value of 1 you can use the following code:

```
SELECT branch, number
FROM table1
WHERE number IN (
 SELECT number
 FROM table1
 GROUP BY number 
 HAVING (COUNT(number ) = 1)
)
AND branch = 1
```

For a demo see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97145/62